# KVM/virt-manager fails to find/load ROMs

Tags: 12.04, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

I'm trying to create a Windows 7 KVM guest on Ubuntu 12.04 using `virt-manager`.

After filling in the various config options,  when it goes to begin installation,I get an error box saying:

> Unable to complete install: 'Unable to read from monitor: Connection reset by peer'

Further digging reveals log file in `/var/log/libvirt/qemu/` indicating several compalaints:

1. `Could not open option rom '/usr/share/qemu/vapic.bin': Permission denied`
2. `pci_add_option_rom: failed to find romfile "pxe-virtio.rom"`
3. `Could not read keymap file: 'en-us'`

I don't understand what the problem with `vapic.bin` is - it is in the location specified and readable:

```
ls -la /usr/share/qemu/vapic.bin

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 9216 Feb 28 11:01 /usr/share/qemu/vapic.bin*
```

`pxe-virtio.rom` is also there:

```
ls -al /usr/share/qemu-linaro/pxe-virtio.rom 

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 63488 Feb 10  2012 /usr/share/qemu-linaro/pxe-virtio.rom

ls -al /usr/share/qemu/pxe-virtio.rom

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 63488 Feb 10  2012 /usr/share/qemu/pxe-virtio.rom
```

I could use some help fixing the `"permission denied"` on `vapic.bin`,  and some help
understanding where `pxe-virtio.rom` is expected to be found (assuming it must be expecting someplace other than `/usr/share/qemu`?),  or how to configure that explicitly?

full log:

```
2013-05-07 06:27:36.780+0000: starting up

LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin 
QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none 
/usr/bin/kvm -S -M pc-1.0 -enable-kvm -m 8024 -smp 2,sockets=2,cores=1,threads=1 -name Win7 -uuid 88384f67-0c25-62be-d564-5fb6ad182caf -nodefconfig -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/Win7.monitor,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=localtime -no-reboot -no-shutdown -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/Windows7.img,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0,format=raw -device ide-drive,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-0,id=ide0-0-0,bootindex=2 -drive file=/Archive/iso/Win7-x64-sp1.iso,if=none,media=cdrom,id=drive-ide0-1-0,readonly=on,format=raw -device ide-drive,bus=ide.1,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-1-0,id=ide0-1-0,bootindex=1 -netdev tap,fd=18,id=hostnet0 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:e6:4a:49,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -usb -device usb-tablet,id=input0 -vnc 0.0.0.0:0 -vga std -device intel-hda,id=sound0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4 -device hda-duplex,id=sound0-codec0,bus=sound0.0,cad=0 -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5

char device redirected to /dev/pts/1

Could not open option rom '/usr/share/qemu/vapic.bin': Permission denied

kvm: -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:e6:4a:49,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3: pci_add_option_rom: failed to find romfile "pxe-virtio.rom"

Could not read keymap file: 'en-us'
2013-05-07 06:27:37.413+0000: shutting down
```

Comment: These option ROMs are only required for PXE booting as far as I know. Failing to read these are probably unrelated to your installation error. The "Unable to read from monitor" is the [Qemu monitor](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Monitor).

Answer (score 0):

Check the status of SELinux with the following command:

> sudo getenforce

if Enforcing, then try:

> sudo setenforce 0

Just a thought.